# What language feature in Kotlin that can cause memory leaks?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, jvm, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin, I love the new language for Android, But I am scared to use it in production and causing a memory leak by accident, Is there any guide for new Kotlin developer showing what can cause memory leaks, What are the solutions to prevent it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kotlin runs on the same JVM as Java or any other JVM based language. As such, it uses the same *garbage collector* as Java, providing a generally memory leakage safe runtime environment.

Nevertheless, memory leaks are still possibles. A common source of such leaks is holding on objects references *longer* than necessary — sometimes forever! — resulting in memory leakage. Some common practices against such leaks are:

- be sure to set your *[nullable references](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)* to `null` as soon as they are no longer needed. This applies mainly to global/static vars; when an object goes out of scope naturally you shouldn't worry about that (for instance, a local variable inside a function).
- using *[weak references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)*. This is a somewhat advanced feature, enabling you to inform the GC that a given reference should be disposed automatically under certain conditions (i.e., GC sets it to `null` for you).

As you may have guessed by now, these *exact* same issues/practices apply to Java code as well.

There several major developers already using Kotlin for their *production* Android apps (e.g., Pinterest, Basecamp, Square, [Trello](http://talkingkotlin.com/Kotlin-at-trello/), etc). So rest assured, you are in good company ;)

Comment: It is same as in Java, basically